# Vue route change but page info shows previous route details

Tags: vue.js, pug

I have a header with multiple links to different pages and when i click on a link the content in the body changes as expected but when i click on a diff header link. i see the route url change properly but the body content shows the previous link. Once i hit refresh i see the proper body content i am expecting. I am not sure if the issue is with binding the html or with how i am loading my vue component that displays the body content.

so the idea is i have header links that show on all pages: Classes, Teachers, Students. when i click on Teachers i get the list of teachers to appear in the body. When i click on Students i see the url change to students but i am still seeing the Teachers content. Once i hit refresh i see the students content.

Header:

```
ul
 li(v-for='link in links')
  router-link(:to='{name: "LinkPage", params...}'){{link.name}}
```

In my view page i have:

```
h1 {{link.name}}
```

In my script:

```
  beforeMount(){
  //api to make call to get the details for the selected link and set it to link property which i used to load html. 
}
```

Comment: Can you add code for component rendering??

Comment: @Riddhi i am not sure what component you mean. This is my first time working with vue so i am not completely familiar with it.

Answer (score 0):

I am feeling a little lack of more details from your implementation.

From what you show and explain, I guess the component, that you have your `beforeMount` hook in, is being re-used on route change. Components that are being re-used don't get mounted again. You need to use the router's navigation guards or even [in-component navigation guards](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/navigation-guards.html#in-component-guards) to trigger your data updates instead. You can find the specifics of the router's navigation flow [here](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/navigation-guards.html#the-full-navigation-resolution-flow).

If my suspicion is right, I recommend that you consider using dedicated route components (one per route). You could call them e.g. `PageHome`, `PageFoo`, `PageBar`. In addition there's the option of [nested routes](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/nested-routes.html).

These patterns make an app's structure and navigational behaviour much more clear.